# How to tell the machine to search for a `.so` in a specific directory?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am running a bunch Fortran programs on a computation cluster. Due to compiler differences between machines, I cannot compile on the cluster machines and I need to compile the code on my own machine. Now, when I run the code on the cluster, I get a message telling me that `libgfortran.so.1` is missing. I asked the cluster admin to install this and he prefer not to. He told me I can copy the file from my own machine to the cluster and place it in a desired folder and then place an entry in the `~/.login` file of my home directory (shared between all the machines in the cluster)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/yotama9/lib
```

I did this but the message remain. So I tried to place this in my `~/.bashrc` and in the job file (a bash script which is used to upload jobs to the cluster)

So how can I direct the machine to search file in the desired path?

Answer (score 4):

I would expect you to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (`PATH` relates to executables, not libraries) variable and export that.

See [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) and [here](http://www.cc.dtu.dk/?page_id=304) for more details

Comment: Can I place this in the bash script file?

Comment: @Yotam: It can happen any time before the [loader](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so) attempts to load the executable.

Comment: I don't know, and perhaps some experimentation is required here

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what about the option ``/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /home/yotama9/lib foo``? Will it run OK? Also, in the admin defence it was a conversation next to the water cooler.

Comment: @Yotam: No. The loader uses an environment variable, not a command line option. And you shouldn't hardcode the loader like that either. Use a subshell if you must. `( export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... ; ./somebinary )`